# My mix-blend-mode text disappears when set to anything other than 'normal'

Tags: html, css

I want my fixed-position text to be visible no matter the background. I considered using mix-blend-mode or adding clipping mask to the text, which would be invisible on the website but visible only "through" the text, but I don't know how to do that. My mix-blend-mode doesn't seem to work either.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 10vh;
  z-index: 1;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.fp-container-1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0vh;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: white;
}

.fp-container-2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0vh;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="blending-group">
  <h1 class="header">Header</h1>
  <div class="fp-container-1"></div>
  <div class="fp-container-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a `background-color` on the element you set the `mix-blend-mode`.  Otherwise, the container will have a background-color of `transparent` by default and therefore have nothing against which to calculate the difference (or whatever mode you chose).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  background: cadetblue;
}

.fp-container-1 {
  height: 100vh;
}

.fp-container-2 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="blending-group">
  <h1 class="header">Header</h1>
  <div class="fp-container-1"></div>
  <div class="fp-container-2"></div>
</div>
```